# Convert stash to working change delimited by #ifdef SYM

Tags: git

I have a set of changes in `stash@{4}` that I would like to apply, but in such a way that the changes are merged into the working copy (or else a new commit) such that either version can be selected by a preprocessor symbol.

(This is a feature of the GNU diff and diff3 programs: see the `--ifdef` option.)

For instance a hunk like

```
@@ -123,7 +123,7 @@
 a
 b
 c
-foo
+bar
 d
 e
 f
```

is actually applied to the working file as

```
a
b
c
#ifdef SYM
bar
#else
foo
#endif
d
e
f
```

If `SYM` is defined, the text corresponds to the patched version, whereas if it is not defined, the text expands to the base version.

Perhaps this can be done with `git merge`, somehow telling `git` to use `diff3 --ifdef=SYM` for merging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious just struck me: `patch` has an `--ifdef/-D` option as well.

```
git stash show -p stash@{4} | patch -p1 -D SYMBOL
```

Done!